# Is it possible to read the contents of a file which was sourced by an interactive shell?

Tags: zsh

I've just deleted by accident a file which was sourced by my `zsh` shell: `~/.shrc`.

I've been able to restore a backup which is 3 months old. But it may miss some configuration which I included in the file during the last few weeks.

The shell from which I deleted the file is still open. So, I dumped the aliases, environment variables, and functions with these commands:

```
alias >~/backup_alias
env   >~/backup_env
function >~/backup_function
```

With these information and the old backup, I should be able to restore most of the contents of the file. Except for the comments. I comment my functions, aliases, environment variables settings a lot, and I often change them.

Since the file has been sourced when the shell was started, and since the shell is still open, is there a command which I could execute from the latter to dump the contents of the file, or at least some parts of it, including the comments?

I'm using `zsh` version `5.3.1`.

Comment: AFAIK, no. The comments are thrown away in the parsing of the file. The file is never read as complete text that is stored somewhere in memory in its original form.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you very much for your comment. I'll see what I can do with what I have.

Comment: You could also try to look for backups left  by some text editors that could be newer than your latest  FS backup.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This is how I got the old backup. I use Vim, and I have enabled the `'undofile'` option (`set undofile` + `set undodir^=$HOME/.vim/tmp/undo`). I've reopened an empty file with the right name, hit `u` to undo, and from there I've been able to retrieve a lot of the contents. But for some reason, the most recent version of the file inside Vim's undotree is 3 months old. The file was in a Dropbox folder, and I asked the shell to read a symbolic link pointing to the latter. In theory, I should have access to a version history.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But the version history in Dropbox is empty. I think that's because of the way I deleted the file. I was renaming files, and recreating symbolic links. At one point, I deleted the file, thinking that it was only the symbolic link, not the real file. In the past, the version history of Dropbox has always saved me in similar circumstances. But not this time. I guess it's time to use git to version control all config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when a shell parses a shell source code for execution, it is unlikely that the text of the file that is parsed will ever be stored as a whole in memory.

Even if the shell reads the complete script, as is, into a memory buffer, that buffer is unlikely to hang around after the script has finished executing, and no shell has any facilities to access such data anyway.

Your best bet is, I believe, to do exactly what you're doing; start from a recent backup of the file and dump the aliases, functions and environment from the currently active shell. Then reconstruct the file from those pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The shell will have read and discarded the data read from there. But depending on how memory was allocated and freed, there is still a remote chance that the data or portions of it is still in the process' memory.

Try running `gcore` (shipped with `gdb`) on the shell process' pid, and see if the content of the file can be found in there (for instance, using `grep -az 'a text you know to be in that file' core.pid` (assuming GNU `grep`).

Try to use that shell as little as possible before doing that to maximise the chances that the memory regions have not been overwritten.

That's a trick I use sometimes when I press `^W` by mistake in `firefox` while entering some text in a form.

Comment: I've dumped an image of the process memory inside a core file with this command `gcore -o /path/to/file 3254` (`3254` was the shell pid). Then, I've started gdb, asking it to execute the `zsh` binary and to read the core file: `gdb /bin/zsh /path/to/core`. One of the message printed by `gdb` was `Reading symbols from /bin/zsh...(no debugging symbols found)...done.` So, I suppose I won't be able to read some information, because I didn't compile the `zsh` binary with the debugging symbols.

Comment: From `gdb`, I've executed `help`. The only section which seems relevant is `data`. `help data` shows a lot of commands, but I don't know what they do exactly. If you could show how you retrieve a lost text in a form in firefox, with `gdb`, or point me to a link which explains a little how to procede, I would really appreciate. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @user852573, do a `grep -az 'a text you know to be in that file' /path/to/file`. You'd use `gdb` if you wanted to analyse the structure of that memory dump, but here, you're only interested in recovering data off it.